# React Classes: Referencing class as "this", within an object's function property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, methods, this, jsx

I have finally gotten into using react and ES6 and it's going well but I am finally stumped and could use some direction.

I have got my head around binding `this` to a method to reference the class, but I am trying to go a bit deeper. Take this for example...which works as expected:

```
class App extends Component {

    state = {
        myFirstState: false,
    };

    handleMyFirstState = () => {
        this.setState( { myFirstState : true } );
    };

    render() {

        return (
            <MyComponent handleMySate={ this.handleMyState } />
        );

    }

}

export default App;
```

As the amount of methods increased I decided NOT to pass each method individually as props and to group them in an object first, and to just pass the object as a whole, as a prop. Like So...

```
class App extends Component {

    state = {
        myFirstState: false,
        mySecondState: false
    };

    handleMyFirstState = () => {
        this.setState( { myFirstState : true } );
    };

    handleMySecondSate = () => {
        this.setState( { mySecondState : true } );
    };



    render() {

        const handleStates = {
            first : this.handleMyFirstState,
            second : this.handleMySecondState
        }

        return (
            <MyComponent handleStates={ handleStates } />
        );

    }

}

export default App;
```

Now, I am trying to avoid redundant code and just build the methods as one object with functions as properties before the render begins. Pretty much like this...

```
class App extends Component {

    state = {
        myFirstState: false,
        mySecondState: false
    };

    handleStates = {
        // Here is where 'this' does not reference the App class
        // I get results from the console log but setstate doesn't pass correctly
        first : () => { console.log("First Triggered"); this.setState( { myFirstState : true } ); },
        second : () => { console.log("Second Triggered"); this.setState( { mySecondState : true } ); }
    };

    render() {

        return (
            <MyComponent handleStates={this.handleStates} />
        );

    }

}

export default App;

// I trigger the function like this within MyComponent and I get the console log, but `this.setState` breaks.
<Button onClick={ this.props.handleState.first } >Handle First</button>
```

I have successfully triggered the functions from the child component ,`<MyComponent/>`, using the latter code, but `this` no longer refers to the class and I can't figure out how to bind `this` to `handleStates` since it's not a function.

Is this just not possible or is there another way to handle what I am trying to achieve?

Thank you in advance!

**ADDITIONAL**

If I move the `handleStates` into the `render()` it works just fine...how could that be?

```
class App extends Component {

    state = {
        myFirstState: false,
        mySecondState: false
    };

    render() {

       const handleStates = {
            first : () => { this.setState( { myFirstState : true } ); },
            second : () => { this.setState( { mySecondState : true } ); }
        };

        return (
            <MyComponent handleStates={this.handleStates} />
        );

    }

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

First, in the second example, you pass `this.handleStates` as the value for the prop `handleStates`, but it's undefined. You built `handleStates` as a local variable, and thus you want your props to reference that local variable:

```
<MyComponent handleStates={handleStates} />
```

For your third (last) example, your issue is even simpler: you defined `handleStates` as an attribute on `this` which is assigned an object, itself with two attributes, `first` and `second`, each of which have a function as their value.

When you ultimately pass `this.handleStates` to `MyComponent`, you're passing an object, not a function. If you want to call one of `first` or `second` from `MyComponent`, you can do so like this:

```
this.props.handleStates.first()
```

Which has the desired result of updating the state in `App`.

For what it's worth, there's a more common pattern for this: simply pass a single updater function as the prop, named according to what it does:

```
class Sandwich extends React.Component {
  this.state = {
    bread: "",
    meat: "",
    veggie: "",
  }

  updateSandwich = (component, selection) => {
    this.setState({ [component]: selection })
  }

  render() {
    return(<IngredientSelector updateSandwich={this.updateSandwich} />)
  }
}

class IngredientSelector extends React.Component {
  return(){
    <button value="Rye" onClick={() => this.updateSandwich("bread", "rye")} />
    <button value="Wheat" onClick={() => this.updateSandwich("bread", "wheat")} />
    <button value="Ham" onClick={() => this.updateSandwich("meat", "ham")} />
    <button value="Turkey" onClick={() => this.updateSandwich("meat", "turkey")} />
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, the second example was a typo as I was creating an example to show for the question. I will fix that. I know how to call the functions within the components in example three. I set a console log within each function which triggers, it's just the "this" reference which has got me confused.

Comment: I like the example approach, but, again, my example is pretty dumbed down. It's not always just setting the state but I will take your example to heart. The crux of the issue is the `this` reference.

Comment: `this` depends on the context. In the third example, those functions are defined as closures. The value for `this` is already bound to your `App` component. It doesn't matter where they're called, `this` won't change as long as you don't re-bind them.

Comment: Can you expound on that? I updated my third example to point to the issue a bit better. I assumed I had to bind `this` within the object property function since it's never bound up until that point. Without the binding, as in example one or two, `this` does not reference the `app`.

Comment: Arrow functions do not have their own `this` value. The value of `this` inside an arrow function is always inherited from the enclosing scope. So in your example, `this` referred to the instance of your component. With normal closures you don't get this behavior and instead `this` is going to be `window` or `undefined`.